# Calculate fund size given risk limit?

Tags: portfolio-management, risk-management

I was listening to a podcast and this guy mentioned the following (literally):

> The entire group is probably running 800 million at risk. So I'm going
> to say like call that like a, if you think of risk as the 1% tail risk
> you said may 250 million standard deviation, so it's probably
> somewhere around like a two and a half to $3 billion hedge fund
> running at 10% volatility.

So, I am trying to work backwards from 3 billion number to understand their thinking. If you have a 3 bn dollar fund, given 10% vol your 99% VaR is going to be `3*0.1*2.33`, assuming normal distribution ~700 million dollar risk. Is this correct? What is going on here?

Comment: Sounds like he was being approximate.  I think your calc is correct.